# component styleUrls with absolute path

Tags: angular

If my component needs an extra style sheet from somewhere else, how do I use the absolute path to get to it?

```
@Component({
    styleUrls: ['absolute_path/another.css']
})
```

I know I can do absolute path with `import` like below as long as I set up `@app` in the config:

```
import { something } from '@app/something'
```

Is there a way to achieve the same/similar thing with the `styleUrls`? The reason is that if my component is too deep in the project tree, the relative path will end up with too many dots, eg:

```
styleUrls: ['../../../../css/another.css']
```

Answer (score -2):

use the import in you css file of you component

> @import "absolute_path/another.css"

if there are some global styles that you may reuse many times you can create a common.scss in you shared folder and put in it what you need

Comment: This is not answering the question, merely suggesting a totally different solution.

Answer (score -2):

You have to start with `'/src/...'`

```
@Component({
    styleUrls: ['/src/styles/another.css']
})
```